# Inherited collection of inherited class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I currently have two classes: `item` and `catalog`; the latter contains a list of `item`s and some methods for handling them:

```
class item {
    int index;
    vector<item*> related_items;
    // other member variables and functions
}

class catalog {
    size_t length;
    item* items;
public:
    catalog(size_t l);
    ~catalog();         // delete[] items;
    // other member variables and functions
}

catalog::catalog(size_t l) {
    items = new item[length = l];
    // Set properties of new items
}
```

(I don't think it would make any difference if `items` were a `vector<item>` instead.) Some of the initialization of an `item`, like populating the list `related_items`, needs the full set of `item`s, so is done in the `catalog` constructor.

Now I would like to define new classes: `book`, which represents a specific type of `item`, and `library`, which is a type of `catalog` that holds `book`s. I would like the `library` constructor to allocate memory for a certain number of `book`s and then initialize those members of `book` that are inherited from `item` in exactly the same way that `catalog` does. It would then do some further initialization of the remaining members of `book`.

My initial idea was to make these derived classes, of `item` and `catalog` respectively. But as it stands, `library` can't be a derived class of `catalog`, because `catalog` has a pointer to an array of objects of the base class. What is the "best" way of implementing this kind of structure?

Comment: Templates and [template specialization](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html) perhaps?

Comment: What is wrong with library inherting from catalog ?? It would point to an array of items too, but in your case, all those items are going to be books.

Comment: @Othman Then you would have [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing), because `items` is an array of `item` *objects*.

Comment: Syntactically valid examples wouldn't hurt

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: No it's not. It's a pointer to zero or more objects that have `item` as a base. Or would be if you added some `virtual` :)

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit It would work if `items` was an array of pointers to `item`. But it's not an array of pointers, it's an array of objects.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Well, if he doesn't change _any_ of his code, sure.... but then what are we talking about?

Answer (score 2):

If `catalog` contained an array of pointers instead, say `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<item>>` it could then hold any subtypes of `item`. A `library` inheriting `catalog` could have member functions only accepting `book`s (which inherit from `item`) and it could cast the pointers appropriately when returning references to books (or, whatever you want to do with them).

Another alternative is templates:

```
template<class T>
class catalog {
    std::vector<T> items;
};

class library: public catalog<book> {
    // ...
};
```

One drawback of templates is that subtypes of different `catalog` instances don't have a common parent. Whether that is important depends on your design.

Since you don't have any member functions in your example, it's quite hard to tell if inheritance makes any sense at all. `library` could contain a `catalog<book>` member, or maybe you can use `catalog<book>` as it is without a separate `library` class.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I would like to avoid having to `dynamic_cast` an `item*` into a `book*`, but I admit this is mainly for aesthetic reasons. I think I will end up going even further down the template path, and use both `template<class T> class item` and `template<class T> class catalog`. When (if) I sort out the details, I'll post as an answer.

Comment: `static_cast` is enough *if* `library` makes sure that only `book`s exist in the vector.